# Is Clara Oswald biologically related to Susan Foreman and/or The Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

I have been watching the last half of Series 7 of **DOCTOR WHO (2005)** and something was brought to my attention. Susan Foreman has been mentioned a couple of times. And, in the 1996 television movie The Doctor mentions that he is half-human...on his mother's side.

Is it possible that Clara is biologically related to Susan and/or The Doctor in some way?

Comment: ...have you finished Series 7?

Comment: Rule #1: The Doctor lies...

Comment: Yes..I have watched literally EVERY episode..old and new. And I know he lies. :)

Comment: Even the lost episodes?

Comment: @TravLane: If the age listed in your profile is correct, it is literally impossible for you to have watched every episode.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, most Dr. Who fans consider the TV movie to be in continuity only in a 'broad strokes' sense -- so they ignore the half-human plot element, but count McGann as the Eighth Doctor.

Given the nature of the show anything is possible, but I'm aware of no evidence or even vague hints that Clara is related to the Doctor biologically. There's a whole bunch of weird timey-wimey bullshitty-wullshit attached to her, but *biologically* she's 100% human (and as far as the fans -- and the show, which *so far* has not brought up the 'half human' element, though of course the showrunners are always free to do what they like -- are concerned, that rules out any biological relationship).

Answer (score 0):

Could Clara's grand mother and father be the lost Susan and Alex(could he have been saved)? Making Clara the Doctor's great-great grand-daughter and part Gallifreyan.

Quote from Tardis Wiki:
 At some point, Susan was taken to the Black Archive by UNIT to have her record as a companion of the Doctor taken, her memories of the visit were subsequently erased and she was sent on her way. (TV: The Day of the Doctor)

Alex: Unlike his mother, as a Gallifreyan/human hybrid, Alex Campbell had one heart (AUDIO: An Earthly Child) and no telepathic or regenerative faculties; only 7% of his genome was Gallifreyan. (AUDIO: Relative Dimensions)